# Can a DC Computer Account be recreated?

Tags: active-directory, replication

We have a problem with an active directory, 
Aftrer some replication issues existing over the years, the first dc has no DC Computer account in the same domain on the other dcs. 
So is it possible to recreate the account, or should we just reinstallone of the dcs ?

Comment: Is it still.. working?  If so, then there's definitely still a computer account.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to have a working DC with no computer account for said DC. My opinion is that the DC is not a DC and/or the computer account exists but has been moved.

Answer (score 3):

With replication issues as thorny as this, let me offer a suggestion that is slightly off topic from your question: **Slash and burn the forest.**

Having worked in a domain that was a bit wonky, things can get so out of hand that you're spending more time propping it up with sticks than you would by simply creating a new AD environment and migrating. If you reinstall the domain controller, you still have replication issues. Can you track them down and fix them? Perhaps, yes. With enough time and a hex editor, anything is possible, but so is creating the entire works of Shakespeare by batting your domain controller with a keyboard for a long enough interval of time. Statistically speaking, it's not going to happen.

The practicality of my suggestion all depends on the size of your AD environment, of course. How many domains, how geographically dispersed, what services are integrated with it, etc. Ultimately, make a new forest on two servers, then choose your most important AD integrated services to move over (Exchange, Lync, SharePoint). You might have to create a trust between the two forests to keep the migration smooth.

To answer your question directly: **I would suggest reinstalling the DC**, but only after all roles have been properly migrated off of it. Reinstall the DC with a ***new name***. However, if you have replication issues, you have the same basic problems, just with a fresh installation.

**Active Directory is like a box of chocolates:** Keep it in a dry, cool place away from children and it won't get messy.